# CSS generated via PHP ignored in Firefox but works in Chrome, IE8

Tags: php, css, browser

i have a weird problem where css generated via php (stuck with a weird cms from an even weider programmer) is ingored by firefox 3.X and probably earlier. But the page loads ok in other browsers like IE7/8 and chrome. Also firebug doesn't see the css either but when i point my browser to the php-css-generation script it show me a plain page with css code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/style.php?PageID=224&Admin=">
```

does anybody know where should i look for some answers or how to possibly fix this? Could there be a problem with that "&Admin=" part?

Comment: You probably need to post some code from the style.php file to troubleshoot. Also it probably can be the fault where the Content-Type header isn't correctly set as "text/css; charset=utf-8"

Comment: and by weird programmer i mean like he's relying on "register_globals on" and "safe_mode off" to make his php scripts work and other very very beyond dark magic

Comment: @thephpdeveloper: i could but it will not help since it's obfuscated :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most likely cause is that you are using PHP's default Content-Type output of `text/html` so Firefox thinks:

> This is a stylesheet written in HTML, a stylesheet language I don't understand and will therefore ignore.

The other browsers are, presumably, compensating for the error.

Add:

```
header('Content-type: text/css');
```

Comment: the "header" should go right at the top of the script right? because looking at firebug i'm allways getting "Content-Type text/plain;charset=windows1250"

Comment: I presume you added this to the top of `style.php`? **Edit:** yes, of course you should :)

Comment: yes i added... but there was an error on my side where firefox fetched the page from the cache ... now i'm getting the right headers but the css is still ignored by firefox and even firebug doesn't see anything

Comment: i used "header('Content-type: text/css; charset=utf-8');" and it works. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

What do you see if you make a direct request (e.g. via your web browser) for app/style.php?PageID=224&Admin= ? Can you debug the response using Firebug?